# How to give back only single values of a list and add it to a specific html element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script from another programmer that is giving back a list to html. How can I only give back single values and then add them to html?

```
$scope.getResult = function() {
      $scope.result = [];

      PAPFields.forEach( function( field ) {
        var name = field[ field.length - 1 ];
        $scope.result.push( [ field[ 0 ], name, +window[ name ] ] );
      } );
    };
```

Comment: Please describe the context a little more. This is obviously AngularJS code, so please provide the template and the expected result.

Answer (score -1):

> Please use for() instead of forEach

```
$scope.getResult = function() {
    $scope.result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < PAPFields.length; i++){
        var name = PAPFields[i][ field.length - 1 ];
        $scope.result.push( [ PAPFields[i][ 0 ], name, +window[ name ] ] );
    }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.